# Audio version of copyrighted written material

Tags: copyright, translation

I want to do a free daily podcast of the Bible. Would I need permission of the copyright holder of the translation I am reading or would this be considered fair use? Would I need to state the source or, conversely, would I be restricted from stating the source without authorization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, yes, the (purported) author of the Bible has much better recourse than the standard Cease & Desist letter -- for example, He could send a plague of locusts or kill your kin and kine -- and arguments about "the [life of the author](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_term)" would probably make things worse rather than better, but, no, He probably won't take any sort of action.

And yes, the translator for any particular version does hold the copyright but there are many, many translations whose copyrights have long since expired.  The King James Version (certainly the most poetic translation) saw its copyright expire before George Washington was born.  There's also the now-public-domain [American Standard Version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Version).

Finally, there are versions released under very flexible licenses.  For example, you can record the [New English Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_English_Translation) without paying a dime so long as you aren't making money off it yourself.

And the translation certainly does matter.  For proof, look no further than Genesis 1:2. The (free!) King James Version reads:

> And the earth was without form, and
>   void; and darkness was upon the face
>   of the deep. And the Spirit of God
>   moved upon the face of the waters.

But the (not free!) New International Version is

> Now the earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters.

There are those who claim that Shakespeare and Marlowe helped out on the KJV.  I don't know if I believe that, but you don't have be a poet to realize that "hovering over the waters" is *not* the image you want to start your Bible with.  Makes the Lord of Hosts sound like He's in a helicopter...

Comment: Funny description, but in reality what it is supposed to mean is that the Spirit of God was vibrating over the waters (in an "agitated" state. It speaks of energy, and is actually deep into physics and other stuff that would be a bit too deep to go into here :D...

Comment: @RolandTaylor  -- If you're into the science of the Bible, read 1 Kings 7:23, where the value for pi is 3.

Comment: that's one of the most silly misunderstandings I've ever seen. Also, take a look at this: http://www.apocalipsis.org/difficulties/pi.htm and this: http://www.thewordteaches.com/questions/math_in_1Kings_7_23.htm You will see that it is actually an error of understanding the original scripture that gives you an answer of 3...

Comment: A small correction: the KJV is out of copyright _almost_ everywhere. It's under perpetual copyright in the UK, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorized_King_James_Version#Copyright_status

Comment: @sjl: I did not know that.  I did some Googling; at least one  close variation on the KJV was considered a "derivative work" and -- although it wasn't clear whether this was tested in court or just the publisher's lawyer's opinion -- therefore separately copyrightable.  A spoken version of the book would be even more "derived" and less a "copy".  If it were me, and I had no business interests in the UK, I would just go ahead and publish.  If Her Majesty's Stationery Office sends me a C&D, so be it, but I think it about as likely as getting complaints from the Original Author.

Comment: @RolandTaylor - if we are going to start hand-waving away bits of the Bible, can we get sodomy back?  Your cites have *different* ways of squinting their eyes at the facts, but that's all they're doing.  If you honestly think the Bible is inerrant, let me ask you, oh, how did Judas die?  Did he hang himself, as in Matthew, or did he just detonate like a grenade, as per Acts?

Comment: @Malvolio: Yer right, the danger is trivial -- more likely than being hit by a meteorite, but not much. (Of course, IANAL, and my free advice may be worth less than you paid for it.)

Comment: @sjl -- plus, breaking the law to promulgate a Bible (at least in the context of a just sovereign) might be working at cross-purposes.

Comment: @malvolio No, the Bible uses the value 3 as an approximation to pi in a calculation in which all the numbers are accurate to only one significant figure. When I was in high school, we had a chemistry test that said, ".0053 grams of salt are added to a beaker containing 200 grams of water. What is the total mass of the contents of the beaker?" Students who answers 200.0053 were marked wrong. The correct answer is 200, because the number is accurate to only one significant digit. If a student in a science class was given a question, "Diameter is 10 meters. What is the circumference?", ...

Comment: ... the correct answer is "30 meters", because the 10 meters is only accurate to one significant digit. Anyone who wrote "31.415926 meters" would and should be marked wrong.

Comment: @Jay --  If I added _40_ grams of salt to a beaker containing 200 grams of water, would the result still be 200 grams?  What if I did it twice?  You can argue the Bible "should" have said 31, because the almost-half-meter is not of significance, or you can argue the Bible shouldn't be taken literally, but to say it is literally true if interpreted under the standards of a 20th Century high-school chemistry class is somewhat tendentious.

Comment: Yes, if you added 40 grams of salt to 200 grams of water you have 200 grams total. If you do it twice then your rounding errors are accumulating. I didn't make this up. Google "significant figures". See, for example, http://www.purplemath.com/modules/rounding3.htm. When you say you weighed it at 200 grams, a chemist would understand that to mean that your scale is accurate to the nearest hundred grams, so a more precise scale might say 210 grams or 180 grams. By the more precise scale we might find that the problem is 170 + 37 + 36 =  243 grams, which your 100 gram scale would measure as 200.

Comment: So you start off saying that the Bible is wrong because it conflicts with your understanding of high school math, but then you think it is somehow illegitimate for me to point out that it is consistent with high school chemistry? Actually I'd say consistent with all chemistry, physics, and any other science that involves measurement. And while the details of how we express significant figures are an invention of relatively modern chemists, the principle is a universal principle of science that applies to all places and all times.

Comment: The Bible is _literally_ false in that it contradicts arithmetic.  Perhaps, there is some very tenuous sense by which it could be rescued by slippery use of the conventions of high-school chemistry.  It could be more readily rescued by saying, "Well, they had it approximately right, in a manner of speaking", certainly what we would say if we were looking at any other document from antiquity.  Doing so with the Bible, however, admits it isn't infallible and should not be taken literally.

Answer (score 6):

The Bible itself isn't under copyright.  A modern translation/interpretation may be, so just stick with one that's in the public domain, eg. The King James Version.

Answer (score 4):

First: Here are no lawyers around, sorry.

Second: You could use a [non-copyrighted](http://www.studylight.org/info/copyright/bible/asv.html). ([More info](http://www.journal33.org/home/translat.htm))

Third: Why don't you just ask the copyright owner?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.

Issue 1: Making a recording of any copyrighted written work is subject to the same restrictions as making your own printed copy. If you were to buy a novel that is still protected by copyright and make an audio book of it without permission from the copyright owner and sell copies of this recording, they could sue you for copyright violation and easily win.

Issue 2: In general, copyright is good for the life of the author plus 70 years. So the copyright on the original Greek text of the New Testament ran out about 1900 years ago. The copyright on Genesis ran out something like 3300 years ago.

Issue 3: Translations have their own copyright, separate and distinct from the original work. So, for example, the New International Version was published in 1978. I presume (without checking, I don't think the detail is important here) that it's considered a "work for hire" and so had a 95 year copyright, so that won't run out until circa 2073.

Issue 4: You can quote short excerpts from a copyrighted work without permission. This is called "fair use". Exactly how much you can quote is decided on a case by case basis considering a variety of factors.

Issue 5: Many Bible translations try to simplify number 4 for you by giving explicit permission to copy specified amounts of the text. For example I think the Hohlman says you can copy up to 250 verses as long as you don't copy an entire book. (Some of the short books, like some of the shorter epistles, are less than 250 verses.)

So your choices are:

1. Record the original Greek and Hebrew. I'm guessing that's not practical for you.
2. Use a translation whose copyright has expired, like King James. (I've read that the UK has given the King James a perpetual copyright, and I see that statement repeated in one of the comments on another answer. But in the US, the copyright on King James ran out before there was a US.)
3. Don't record the entire Bible. Just record snippets. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish so this may or may not be practical.
4. Get permission from the copyright owners. They might ask for money, especially if you intend to sell your recordings. Or they might say no. But you can ask.